# Rails - how to use scope on a variable's children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `user_item` that has_many `user_item_images`.  A `user_item` has an attribute called `primary_image_id`.  I want to return all of a `user_item`'s `user_item_images` where `user_item.primary_image_id` does not equal `user_item_image.id`.

I want to take the returned array and run an .each iterator on it.

Something like `@user_item.user_item_images.where(user_item.primary_image_id != user_item_image.id).each...`

I might need to create an instance variable of the array in the controller but not sure the easiest way to do this.

I was having difficulty searching for my answer because I don't really know how to word this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using rails 4, you can use the `not` method.

`user_item.user_item_images.where.not(id: user_item.primary_image_id)`